# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pqxx::syntax_error'?

Tags: c++, postgresql

I'm new to postgre sql, and I made a program that queries a database. When I tried to run my program with this query, I got the error in the subject. Is there something wrong with the way I wrote my query? The error was specifically:

> what():  ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
>
> LINE 1: SELECT * FROM Student
>
> WHERE Student.surname = 'Smith';

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Student"\
         "WHERE Student.surname = 'Smith';";
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to write the tablename.property.
you only need to write the property like that : 
SELECT * FROM weather
    WHERE city = 'San Francisco' AND prcp > 0.0;

Comment: I tried your edit, then it gave me an error near the equal sign?

Answer (score 0):

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Student"\
      "WHERE Student.surname = 'Smith';";
```

is equal to writing

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM StudentWHERE Student.surname = 'Smith';";
```

you need something more between Student and WHERE.